# One year later, is Heartbleed still something the end-user needs to be careful against?

Tags: heartbleed

I'm running [Chromebleed](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromebleed/eeoekjnjgppnaegdjbcafdggilajhpic?hl=en) to defend against sites affected by Heartbleed, but it's been a *very* long time since I've used a site that was still vulnerable. By now I would think the vast majority of the Internet has upgraded to protect against the vulnerability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search returns a few articles discussing Heartbleed one year after the announcement.

Fortune magazine on April 7 2015 [cites a report](http://fortune.com/2015/04/07/heartbleed-anniversary-vulnerable/) saying that 74% of the Fortune 2000 have still not patched.

So, yes, this is still a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Heartbleed affects many things that aren't web servers, like embeded devices,VPN,SMTP or VoIP services. There is also a big difference between what gets patched on internet facing and local networks. Given that I still stumble upon windows NT4 boxes during pentests I expect to see heartbleed for many years to come.